# Multi Language Code Snippet in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, syntax-highlighting

I write Programming articles in my Wordpress website.

My articles contain content for different languages with code samples.

I want to allow user to choose which programming language he prefer.

Example from Android documentation where user can chose `Kotlin` or `Java` code:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked for a plugin that already provides this functionality, or tried writing some code?

Comment: I have tried plug-ins but they provide only one language